# Angular 8 prevent dropdown field scroll trigger the windows scroll event

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a top nav bar and when scroll down the page need to do some css changes on the navbar.

So i using window.addEventListener in my shared header.component.ts to detect the scroll event. But if in other components have dropdown field will scrollbar will also trigger the changes navbar css function.

How do I limit the dropdown field do not trigger the changes navbar css function?

> header.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
  }

  scroll = (event: any): void => {
    const number = event.srcElement.scrollTop;
    const element = document.querySelector('.navbar');
    if (number > 50) {
      element.classList.add('toolbar-scroll');
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('toolbar-scroll');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this by look through all the event one by one and find *event.target.firstChild.nodeName* has a unique variable which can be used to differentiate component with the drop-down field

```
if (event.target.firstChild.nodeName === 'ROUTER-OUTLET') {
      if (number > 50) {
        element.classList.add('toolbar-scroll');
      } else {
        element.classList.remove('toolbar-scroll');
      }
    }
```